# Drawing Polygons with leaflet in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, slider

I have a geospatial dataset of monthly average temperatures in the US. I want to display this as a leaflet map in a Shiny app. With a time-slider, users should be able to select a visualisation of each month.

When I try to run my data with codes I found online I run into a number of problems and unfortunately I don't understand exactly where which data is needed.

On Wetransfer I uploaded my dataset [Data](https://www.transferxl.com/download/08jsSTc0pcCypw).

Relevant info about the dataset: I want the slider to run by either the "Valid_Seas" column (monthly values by parts of the US) or "values". The polygons (column: Geometry) should be colored by the column "Prob", this is the monthly average temperature.

Regarding the R.skript: Starting at line 215 is my attempt to create the ShinyApp map, just a you can see here:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                style="z-index:500;", # legend over my map (map z = 400)
                tags$h3("Average Temperature"), 
                sliderInput("periode", "Months 2021",
                            min(tempyear21$values),
                            max(tempyear21$values),
                            value = range(tempyear21$values),
                            step = 1,
                            sep = ""
                )
  )
)

#bis hier hin stimmt es 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # reactive filtering data from UI
  
  reactive_data_chrono <- reactive({
    tempyear21 %>%
      filter(Valid_Seas >= input$periode[1] & Valid_Seas <= input$periode[2])
  })
  
  
  # static backround map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(tempyear21) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(-49.57,24.91,-166.99,68.00)
  })  
  
  # reactive circles map
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", data = reactive_data_chrono()) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addMarkers(lng=~lng,
                 lat=~lat,
                 layerId = ~id) # Assigning df id to layerid
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am very much looking forward to any advice. Kind regards

Pernilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spotted three problems with your code. First, your input slider returns number(s), while your data set column `Valid_Seas` is character ("Jan 2021", etc.). Hence, after you apply `filter` the dataset is reduced to zero rows. Better use the `values` column instead.

Second, if you wanted to display month by month, you should pass only one single number as `value` argument to `sliderInput`, like

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
    absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                style="z-index:500;", # legend over my map (map z = 400)
                tags$h3("Average Temperature"), 
                sliderInput("periode", "Months 2021",
                            min(tempyear21$values),
                            max(tempyear21$values),
                            value = min(tempyear21$values), # !
                            step = 1,
                            animate=TRUE, # add play button
                            sep = ""
                )
    )
)
```

Otherwise, you get an overlay of several months.

Third problem: your dataset has polygons, in your server function you use `addMarkers`. You need to use `addPolygons` instead. In order to fill the polygons, you need to determine a color for each number. The `classInt` and `RColorBrewer` packages can help you with that:

```
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
n <- 3 # number of categories
pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, "Reds")
ivar <- classInt::classIntervals(
    tempyear21$Prob, n=n, style="quantile"
) 
tempyear21$colcode <- classInt::findColours(ivar, pal)
legend_names <- names(attr(tempyear21$colcode, "table"))
```

As for the server function, I think you are on the right track with `leafletProxy`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {        
    # static map elements
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() |> addTiles() |> 
        fitBounds(-49.57,24.91,-166.99,68.00) |>
        addLegend(position="topleft", colors=pal, labels=legend_names)
    })
    
    # map handler
    map_proxy <- leafletProxy("map", session)
    
    # react on slider changes
    observeEvent(input$periode, {
        dat <- subset(tempyear21, values == input$periode)
        map_proxy |> leaflet::clearShapes() |>
        leaflet::addPolygons(
            data=dat,
            weight=1,
            color=dat$colcode, # border
            opacity=1,
            fillColor=dat$colcode 
        ) 
    })  
}
```